# How to find missing time series or irregularities in time series?

Tags: r, time, interpolation, series

I have a data frame of two column , first column is time series for 2010 year as per hours and other one is temp. values , there should be 8760 value in row but I have 8752 values, SO I have 8 values missing , I would like to fill the gap of this time series and add the values  in second column as respective , I tried interpolation but it little bit tricky and I am still learning and new in programming. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: th package `forecast` has a function called `na.interp` and `zoo` has `na.approx` among other packages.

Comment: You should also check the help pages on this website on how to post a question.